Reliable setup of MCU and cellular modem
I want to measure various environmental data (temperature, humidity etc.) on farmland.
To transfer the data, I'd like to use a cellular connection. There are devices for this out there like the Arduino MKR, Ikarus Boards or others that use either the nRF9160 or some u-Blox board. I tried using these devices but i always ran into various errors like an unresponsive sim module, the mcu cannot be programmed anymore or that no deep sleep was available. So what I need is a device that can reliably send data over a cellular connection.
My thought was, that we already have such devices. Phones obviously! Only downside there is, i don't know a single phone that can read data from a sensor. Maybe with an additional Arduino and the USB connection this could be possible though.
The phone would also need to power itself down and up again in regular intervalls to transmit the data. Does there any phone/device come to your mind that would suit my needs?
Something like the Arduino MKR, but created by a company that acually knows how to build phones or cellular products. I need more reliability than what the maker models offer.

You are assuming that the cellular problems are due to hardware design, but I'd guess they are probably software-related. I designed a very high-volume cellular product, and the key to reliability was putting in a lot of error-handling code, to handle the various connectivity problems that arise from time to time. The hardware was fairly standard with a microcontroller, GSM & GPS modules; the only addition to increase reliability was a hardware watchdog. The end result was very reliable; I don't think you will do better than that with a mobile phone.

But error handling can only do so much. For example, the Arduino MKR just can't be programmed anymore. The nrf9160 feather from circuitdojo cannot use the RTC for interrupts and I don't know anything about antenna design. I'm more experienced in software development, so I'd like to rely on the hardware somebody else designed. What MCU and Modems did you use?

If you replace robotics with IoT, this article explains my situation pretty good: https://spectrum.ieee.org/the-mythical-non-roboticist

We used an STM32 MCU, and Telit modems such as the GL865. The key to reliability is to track the modem state in the MCU code; there are various ways the modem can get (temporarily) confused and unresponsive, and if you just churn out more AT commands, you can end up with a mismatch between the state machines in the modem and the MCU, with very confusing results. Also we used UDP rather than TCP, since the latter generates more traffic (a lot more, if there are any errors). With UDP, just send the block twice, and if no response, send it again a minute later.

I looked for the GL865. There I stumbled upon a devboard from Mikroe. I have their LTE IoT Click 7 with a SARA R422M8S on it. This thing has the issue that I can open a single connection and send some data. Afterwards the chip becomes unresponsive sometimes. Additionally, the onboard capacitor is too small. Only after adding 4.7μF the energy supply was stable enough. So how do I know if their GL856 devboard has similar issues? There are no reviews. No instructions on which antenna to use etc. Can you provide details on how you work with these systems?

I'd start by running the standard MicroE code on one of their CPU boards, logging the AT commands to check that everything is working OK. Then I'd simulate various faults, and see what happens. The easiest way to do this is to use a screen box, with a re-radiating antenna linked to an external antenna via an attenuator, then you can simulate a poor RF signal. Or since the board has SMA connectors, you can just try inserting a switchable attenuator between the antenna & board, but that won't work if your cell signal is strong.

As a quick and easy bruteforce shortcut, you can have a timer switch that will just power cycle the MCU and modem every X hours (start with x=1 perhaps !). While you figure things out, you'll still have parameter numbers for the summer. And you wont have to visit the setup physically so many times while you debug the reliability.
